# Populate transient fields Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hi I have my following model under Hibernate/JPA structure:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Provider {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "users_u_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "users_u_id_seq", name = "users_u_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "u_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "u_password", length = 128, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "u_name", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "u_surname", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "j_provider_id")
    private Set<Job> jobs;

    @Transient
    private Integer averageRating;

    @Transient
    private Integer jobsCreated;

    .
    .
    .
```

Before migrating to Hibernate I was using SQL queries to create and populate my objects by hand. Now the object creation is handled by Hibernate so I cant set this values by hand.

As you can see, my Provider entity has a Set of Jobs and this Jobs contain reviews. The averageRating field is the average rating of the Jobs under that provider and the jobsCreated is the number of jobs created by the provider.

The problem is I do not know how to set this properties so that when a new Job is created or a new review is made, these values are updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the logic in the getter method of those fields.

like this.

`public Integer getJobCreated(){   return jobs.size()  }`

Comment: why not edit your answer to add this piece of code? Plus hibernate documentation now recommends annotating the getters rather than field declarations, which makes even more sense in this case

Comment: actually, the query is about the Transient declared field which will not persist to DB. but it can use to do certain operations.